# Passing Firebase data to different screen in React Native Expo

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I've been struggling for a while now to get Firebase working on my app. I'm new to React Native and I'm trying to figure out how I can pass Firebase-data from a component to another screen.

The concept should be very simple. I have a component named 'ArticleItem' that is placed on my home screen as an Array. If a user clicks on this article, he should navigate to a screen called "ArticleScreen" to read the Firebase data.

**Code of home screen** (ArticleItem is the component with data from Firebase):

```js
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("ArticleScreen", {
      section: card
    });
  }}
>
  <ArticleItem />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

**ArticleItem component**

```js
return (
  <Container>
    <ListView
      horizontal={true}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      enableEmptySections
      dataSource={this.ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.listViewData)}
      renderRow={data => (
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <View style={styles.card}>
            <ImageBackground
              source={{ uri: data.val().image }}
              style={[styles.imageView]}
            >
              <Text style={styles.text}>
                {data.val().name}
                {data.val().servings}
                {data.val().category}
              </Text>
              <Text> {data.val().description}</Text>
            </ImageBackground>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
    />
  </Container>
);
}
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ArticleItem);
```

**ArticleScreen** where users should find all firebase data (kept it simple for experimentation purposes

```js
class ArticleScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Container>
          <Text>{data.val().name}</Text>
        </Container>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ArticleScreen);
```

I sincerely hope someone is able to help me! Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the value from the navigation as below

```js
state = {
    search: this.props.navigation.getParam("section", "Default value")
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!! I suppose this state would live on the ArticleScreen? And currently I'm unable to navigate to this ArticleScreen. Is this because of missing a state?

Comment: None, I can click on the component but it doesn't navigate to the ArticleScreen....

Comment: Earlier you were able to navigate? If yes, Comment getParam code and try again.

Comment: No, so figuring out now what to do